# Move last child to first position

Tags: jquery

My HTML:

```
  <div id="my-slider">
    <img src="/slider/pic/bf3.jpg" alt="picture">
    <img src="/slider/pic/bf3_cq.jpg" alt="picture">
    <!-- etc -->
  </div>
```

On specific event I want to move last img tag to first position (according to parent)

I try:

```
    curr.css('left', 0);
    curr.prepend(curr.parent());
```

I can change css, but second line raising error:

> HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point
>   in the hierarchy

Could someone give me any advice?

Comment: why change the css? can't you use: "remove()" last image tag (assign to var) + "before()" img:first?

Comment: I need this, I try to make circular slider

Comment: you can always use detach (instead of remove) and prepend...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
curr.parent().prepend(curr);
```

or

```
curr.prependTo(curr.parent());
```

Comment: Don't we need to `.detach()` it?
Or prepend will detach it implicitly?

Comment: prepending an element that already exists in the DOM will just move it, so there's no need to detach() it first.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `prepend()`:

```
$('#my-slider').prepend($('#my-slider img:last'))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Uttv8/

Answer (score 6):

try out this    http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/TFYXA/

```
$("#my-slider img:last-child").prependTo("#my-slider")
```