# moving last child to first position does not work jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have tried moving last element in my list to first position on click, but it does not work. I did it according to answer from this question: [Move last child to first position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700995/move-last-child-to-first-position) . Firebug shows me that something happens with the list, but it's certainly not last to first change :(

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(".carousel-button-left").click(function(){
    var $ul=$(this).next();                 
    var $lastchild=$ul.children().last();
    $ul.prepend($lastchild);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="testowyDiv">
    <img class="carousel-button-left" src="ikony/strzalkal.png">
    <div class="testowyDiv2">
        <ul class="testowyUl">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>8</li>
            <li>9</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <img class="carousel-button-right" src="ikony/strzalkap.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(".carousel-button-left").click(function(){
    var $ul=$(this).next().find(".testowyUl");   // by next we reach on next div then by find we reach on ul               
    var $lastchild=$ul.children().last();
    $ul.prepend($lastchild);
    });
});
```

Comment: one note: I recommend using `.closest(sth).find(sth)` over `.next(sth).find(sth)`. What if you place an element between the ul and its corresponding button?

Comment: we use closest to go on parent level when we talk sibling , next, prev  the  use next,pre and sibling method in jquery   and i accept it by these  we depends on dom by closest we go on directly but here i think next is great any way your suggestion always welcome thanks @JanDvorak

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(".carousel-button-left").click(function(){
    var $ul=$(".testowyUl");  //do you need node traversing, if not use direct, better keep a id for it 
    var lastchild=$ul.children().last();
        console.log(lastchild.val());
    $ul.prepend(lastchild);
    });
});
```

[Demo -Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mvtpn/)

Comment: Same problem as the other downvoted answers: this will break if there are multiple lists.

Comment: what about using a id instead of class to avoid, node traversing & breaking as you suggested

Comment: Then it cannot be used with multiple lists.

Answer (score -1):

Using prepend or insertBefore.

Sample:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.carousel-button-left').click(function() {
        var first = $('.testowyUl li:first');
        var last = $('.testowyUl li:last');
        last.insertBefore(first);
    });
});
```

Comment: Will break horribly if there are multiple lists

Comment: Sample just to present the idea. Don't expect some exactly code.

Comment: the code you present will be used by the asker. Don't present (without disclaimers or even with) what you don't want to be used.